# How is file content transmitted on file upload

Tags: javascript, html, http, upload

I uploaded a file using `<input type="file"/>` and I checked the `http request` using chrome devtools.

I can see the file name and size, but not the contents of the file.

How does transfer of the file contents happen?

Is it not `http`?

Comment: "I checked the http request" — How?

Comment: @Quentin updated question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [algorithm is described in the HTML 5 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#multipart-form-data).

In short, the HTTP request body will contain the encoded contents of the files separated by boundary markers with associated meta data.

Chrome's Net tab [doesn't display the file content for performance reasons](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/google-chrome-developer-tools/FaInquBDhU0/aT8bcr9lAQAJ).

Comment: great answer. Do you know any tools I could use to see the payload (other than Wireshark)